# AngularJS/Karma/Jasmine - Service call not returning value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angularjs-1.6

I'm attempting to make a call to a Github API using a service injected into a component - and yes, I am using AngularJS 1.5.3.

In the unit test, I am not receiving back a value (the function does work when I run it in the browser). I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and hopefully someone could point me in the right direction.

Here's the error:
[image]

**main.component.js**

```
(function(){
    angular.module("app").component("mainComponent", {
        templateUrl: "/templates/main.component.html",
        controllerAs: "vm",
        controller: function(APIFactory, UserFactory, $state){
            const vm = this;

            vm.searchGithub = function(){
                APIFactory.getAPI(vm.searchText).then(function(res){
                    res.status !== 200 ? $state.go("404", {errorData: res.data }) : (
                        vm.User = new UserFactory.User(res.data),
                        $state.go("profile", {userData: vm.User})
                    );
                })
                .catch(function(err){
                    $state.go("fourOFour");
                });
            };
        }
    });
})();
```

**main.component.spec.js**

```
describe("Main Component", function(){
    var mainComponent, APIFactory, UserFactory, $httpBackend, $q, $state, $rootScope;

    const addy = "https://api.github.com/users/";

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module("app"));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_APIFactory_, _UserFactory_, _$httpBackend_, _$state_, _$q_, _$rootScope_, _$componentController_){
        APIFactory = _APIFactory_;
        UserFactory = _UserFactory_;
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        $state = _$state_;
        $q = _$q_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $rootScope.$new();
        mainComponent = _$componentController_("mainComponent", { $scope : {} });
    }));

    describe("Checking if the searchGithub() worked correctly", function(){
        var result;

        beforeEach(function(){
            spyOn(mainComponent, "searchGithub").and.callThrough();
            spyOn(APIFactory, "getAPI").and.callThrough();
            result = {};
        });

        it("should make a call to UserFactory", function(){
            mainComponent.searchText = "someName";
            expect(mainComponent.searchText).toBeDefined();

            // RESPONSE_SUCCESS does exist, I've omitted it.
            $httpBackend.whenGET(addy + mainComponent.searchText).respond(200, $q.when(RESPONSE_SUCCESS));

            // This is where I expect something to work

            APIFactory.getAPI(mainComponent.searchText).then(function(res){
                result = res;
            });

            $httpBackend.flush();

            expect(APIFactory.getAPI).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mainComponent.searchText);
            expect(mainComponent.User).toBeDefined();
        });
    });


});
```

Comment: Here's a methodological problem. Instead of focusing on some particular unit you're mixing all units - a controller, services and $httpBackend - into one big mess. When something goes wrong, you don't know at which point it failed. If you're testing a controller here, mock/stub all other services (including $state).

Comment: Change `expect(mainComponent.User).toBeDefined();` to `expect(mainComponent.User).not.toBeDefined();`.

Comment: @estus - I appreciate the good advice. Could you look at my answer and see if you think it's a good solution?

Comment: Yes, it looks closer to what is usually expected from isolated controller test. Still not sure why $httpBackend is there. If there are no requests (getAPI call is mocked), flush() would throw an error. Also, $state should always be stubbed in unit tests. Real router is extra moving part that makes tests unreliable (preferably ngRoute and ui.router modules shouldn't be loaded at all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what I came up with for a solution. If anybody wants to give me a better solution, I am up for ideas.

First I made two mocks and then I injected them into `mainComponent`, as well as a spy for my mocked `APIFactoryMock.getAPI` function:

```
const APIFactoryMock = {
    getAPI: function(){}
};

const UserFactoryMock = {
    User: function(data){
        return {
            login: data.login,
            id: data.id,
            avatar_url: data.avatar_url,
            html_url: data.html_url,
            followers: data.followers,
            following: data.following,
            public_repos: data.public_repos,
            public_gists: data.public_gists,
            created_at: data.created_at,
            updated_at: data.updated_at,
            name: data.name,
            company: data.company,
            blog: data.blog,
            location: data.location,
            bio: data.bio,
            hireable: data.hireable,
            email: data.email,
            links: {
                followers_url: data.followers_url,
                following_url: data.following_url,
                subscriptions_url: data.subscriptions_url,
                repos_url: data.repos_url,
                organizations_url: data.organizations_url
            }
        }
    }
};

beforeEach(inject(function(_APIFactory_, _UserFactory_, _$httpBackend_, _$state_, _$q_, _$rootScope_, _$componentController_){
    APIFactory = _APIFactory_;
    UserFactory = _UserFactory_;
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $state = _$state_;
    $q = _$q_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $rootScope.$new();
    spyOn(APIFactoryMock, "getAPI").and.returnValue(RESPONSE_SUCCESS);
    bindings = { APIFactory: APIFactoryMock, UserFactory: UserFactoryMock, $state: $state };
    mainComponent = _$componentController_("mainComponent", { $scope : {} }, bindings);
}));
```

And then I wrote tests for the mocks:

```
it("should make a call to UserFactory", function(){
        mainComponent.searchText = "someName";
        expect(mainComponent.searchText).toBeDefined();


        mainComponent.searchGithub(mainComponent.searchText);
        $httpBackend.whenGET(addy + mainComponent.searchText).respond(200, $q.when(RESPONSE_SUCCESS));

        $httpBackend.flush();

        mainComponent.User = UserFactoryMock.User(RESPONSE_SUCCESS.data);

        expect(mainComponent.searchGithub).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mainComponent.searchText);
        expect(mainComponent.User).toBeDefined();
        expect(mainComponent.User.id).toEqual(666);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above answer, you are manually making a call to `UserFactoryMock.User` in the testcase, which will create an user object.

But to correctly test the functionality, to should be checking for `UserFactory.User` to be called when call to `APIFactory.getAPI` is success (without making a call to `UserFactory.User` manually in the testcase.

I would suggest modifying your testcase to something like below:

```
describe("Main Component", function(){
var mainComponent, APIFactory, UserFactory, $httpBackend, $q, $state, $rootScope;

const addy = "https://api.github.com/users/";

beforeEach(angular.mock.module("app"));

beforeEach(inject(function(_APIFactory_, _UserFactory_, _$httpBackend_, _$state_, _$q_, _$rootScope_, _$componentController_){
    APIFactory = _APIFactory_;
    UserFactory = _UserFactory_;
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $state = _$state_;
    $q = _$q_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    var scope = $rootScope.$new();
    var bindings = { APIFactory: APIFactory, UserFactory: UserFactory, $state: $state };
    mainComponent = _$componentController_("mainComponent", { $scope : scope }, bindings);
}));

describe("Checking if the searchGithub() worked correctly", function(){
    var result;

    beforeEach(function(){
        spyOn(mainComponent, "searchGithub").and.callThrough();
        spyOn(APIFactory, "getAPI").and.callFake(function() {
            var def = $q.defer();
            def.resolve(RESPONSE_SUCCESS);
            return def.promise;
        });
        spyOn(UserFactory, "User").and.callFake(function() {
            var user = { id: 666, .... };
            return user;
        });
    });

    it("should make a call to UserFactory", function(){
        mainComponent.searchText = "someName";
        $rootScope.$apply();
        expect(mainComponent.searchText).toBeDefined();

        mainComponent.searchGithub(); // Call the same way as it works in the code actually.

        $rootScope.$apply();

        //No manual call to 'UserFactory.User' or 'APIFactory.getAPI'. The call to 'APIFactory.getAPI' is resolved/succeeds, hence a call to 'UserFactory.User' is made and the same is tested
        expect(APIFactory.getAPI).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mainComponent.searchText);
        expect(UserFactory.User).toHaveBeenCalledWith(RESPONSE_SUCCESS.data);
        expect(mainComponent.User).toBeDefined();
        expect(mainComponent.User.id).toEqual(666);
    });
});


});
```

Comment: @les-paul Can you please check the above answer ?